# Rails: obtain user access token usign facebook app without logging user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Situation description:**
I need to dynamically download reviews from an Facebook page to display them on my site. For testing purposes I'm using a page access token generated from the user (page admin) access token (using Graph API Explorer). Unfortunately this token is short lived.

As stated in the Graph API documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) to obtain long lived page access token I need to use long lived user access token. To obtain long lived user access token I need to post a request using short lived user access token and my FB app credentials.

To automate the whole process for the admin of my site I want to obtain his user access token and then process it in the way to obtain a long lived page access token (I created an app specifically for this use).

**My question is**: how can I make a call that asks a user for permission to 'manage_pages' and returns short lived user access token? I don't want it to have anything to do with my site registration and login process, I'm not using Oauth, I'm not logging users via Facebook. I want user to type his FB credentials, grant my app his 'manage_pages' permission and that's it. I'd like it to be as similar to 'Get Access Token' feature in Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).